# Wordpress multiple thumbnails of different sizes

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to look for a plugin/solution that allows me to upload multiple thumbnails of different sizes.

For a post I would need the following:

- 1 thumbnail (90x90)
- 1 larger thumbnail (200x150)
- unlimited feature images (600x300)

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try adding custom fields to the admin system. Either manually by adding custom meta boxes:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Or through a plugin (My preferred option):

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

This way you can upload a different image for each size option you want.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible but not in the sense that a thumbnail is generated, rather another version.

When you currently upload an image, it creates up to 4 versions of the file in varying sizes.

These being:

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

You can add other sizes as well with custom names. To do this, you add a small line of code within your functions.php file like below:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, soft proportional crop mode
```

As there are some limitations with naming and other details about cropping, full detail on this can be found [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Thanks, I did find that documentation before, but this isn't what I want to achieve. I want to be able to upload completely different images, not just one image with different crops.

Comment: Ahh right, i read the question simply as you were trying to add just different image sizes. My bad.